# Where does homebrew install a legacy php version?

Tags: homebrew, php

In order to make some old software work, I need to downgrade my PHP version from 8 to 7.4. I run this command without any problems:

```
brew install php@7.4
```

... and homebrew buzzes and whirs and dutifully installs php 7.4.

Now the problem is that I have no idea where the binary for php 7.4 lives.

I tried `ls -al /usr/local/bin/ | grep "7.4"`, but that didn't come up with any results.

When I do `php -v`, I still get version 8 showing up.

**Where can I find the version-specific legacy binary for php 7.4?**

Comment: Did you look in /usr/local/Cellar?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, have you tried `ls -al /usr/local/bin/ | grep "74"` (without the dot)?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your comments. I tried a grep without the dot, with no luck. But looking in Cellar found it! It's at `/usr/local/Cellar/php\@7.4/7.4.19_1/bin/php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP 8 is already installed, Homebrew won't link an earlier version of PHP to `php`.

1. Try `brew link php@7.4`
2. Otherwise access the Cellar directly: `/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/*/bin/php`